# Having problems trying to assign a component created in component creator to front page

Tags: joomla3.0

I have returned to building a website in Joomla after quite a long time away from it. I've totally forgotten how you assign a module to the front page. I've installed a module that I created in Content Creator which is an online tool for creating MVC based components.

I've enabled the module and I can now create content for this module. It's a module called front page icons.

I select Menus > Main Menu and click on module assignment but it doesn't appear.

I try creating a menu item for this content type and I can do that fine. I can create the menu item right and you open the menu item and there appears a nice little list of my content I've created but I can't assign this to the main page.

I honestly can't remember how to do this, all I remember is that the process is counter intuitive and took me ages to find in the first place.

Any idea?

Comment: It's not appearing in module assignment like I need it to

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this up in Extensions > Modules.

1) Open the module you want to display.

2) Go to the 'Menu Assignment' tab

3) Select 'Only on the pages selected'

4) Check your home page

Also, double check that the module is assigned to a position and is published.

Joomla docs on modules is here: https://docs.joomla.org/Module

Comment: Thanks, that was great advice. It wasn't the answer but the answer was stupid. I'd not payed my component creation bill so it was only creating a component not a module. 

Nobody could have probably guess that as I don't think I provided the right information. Thanks though Blueline. Points awarded for what would normally be the correct answer